# Push all objects after a selected object into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, javascript-objects

I have a web page that returns a list of objects like:

```
date.pdf
names.csv
address.pdf
age.csv
cost.csv
budget.csv
data.pdf
race.pdf
contractors.csv
```

When a user checks `budget.csv`, I want every object with the `.csv` extension from that point to be pushed into `csv_files[]`. If they select `names.csv`, then every `.csv` including and after `names` is pushed into the array.

So the only data that gets pushed into the array is from the selected object downwards. How can I implement this?

Current code

```
const csv_files = []

 $scope.listAllobjects = (err, data) => {

    $.each(data.Contents, (index, value) => {
      if (value.Key.endsWith("csv")) {
        csv_files = [];
}
```

```
 // Handle click on selection checkbox
  $("#filesobjects-table tbody").on("click", 'input[type="checkbox"]', (e1) => {
    const checkbox = e1.currentTarget;
    const $row = $(checkbox).closest("tr");
    const data = $tb.DataTable().row($row).data();
    let index = -1;

    // Prevent click event from propagating to parent
    e1.stopPropagation();

    // Find matching key in currently checked rows
    index = $scope.view.keys_selected.findIndex((e2) => e2.Key === data.Key);

    if (checkbox.checked && data.Key.endsWith("csv")) {
     console.log(selected csv)
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a pure JavaScript solution (Descriptive comments has been added in the below code snippet).

```js
var contentData = ["date.pdf", "names.csv", "address.pdf", "age.csv", "cost.csv", "budget.csv", "data.pdf", "race.pdf", "contractors.csv"];

var myDiv = document.getElementById("cboxes");

for (var i = 0; i < contentData.length; i++) {
  var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  var label = document.createElement("label");
  checkBox.type = "checkbox";
  checkBox.value = contentData[i];
  myDiv.appendChild(checkBox);
  myDiv.appendChild(label);
  label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(contentData[i]));
}

// Event to handle the checkbox click
document.getElementById('getResult').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('showResult').innerHTML = getCheckedValues();
});

function getCheckedValues() {
  // filtered out the checked items.
  const element = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'))
  .filter((checkbox) => checkbox.checked).map((checkbox) => checkbox.value);
  
  // element[0] will always return the first checked element and then we are getting index of that.
  const checkedElemIndex = contentData.indexOf(element[0]);
  
  // Slice the content data to get the elements from the checked element index.
  return contentData.slice(checkedElemIndex, contentData.length)
}
```

```html
<div id="cboxes"></div>

<button id="getResult">Get Result</button>

<pre id="showResult"></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a few ways, I suppose, to approach this problem, but the most intuitive to me is this:

```js
const csvList = ["date.pdf","names.csv","address.pdf","age.csv","cost.csv","budget.csv","data.pdf","race.pdf","contractors.csv"];
const selectedCsv = 'budget.csv';

function getCsvsAfter(csvList, selectedCsv) {
    const filteredCsvs = [];
    let found = false;
    for (let csv of csvList) {
    if (csv === selectedCsv) found = true;
        if (found) filteredCsvs.push(csv);
    }
    return filteredCsvs;
}

console.log(getCsvsAfter(csvList, selectedCsv));
```

Iterate over every csv, and when you've hit the one you're trying to match, set a variable called `found` to `true`. Once it's true, you can add every following csv onto the list.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const list = ['date.pdf','names.csv','address.pdf','age.csv','cost.csv','budget.csv','data.pdf','race.pdf','contractors.csv'];
const selected = 'budget.csv'

const csv_files = list.slice(list.indexOf(selected))

console.log(csv_files)
```